# GWT compilation failed libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gwt, libgdx

with this new setup with gradle, i can't run the html project,
i added to the classpath the universal tween engine, on desktop and android everything works fine,
misteriously eclipse doesn't see the tweenengine.gwt.xml,
i followed this tutorial in order to add the universal tween engine https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

this is the error when i try to run the html project on libgdx

[ERROR] Unable to find 'aurelienribon/tweenengine.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo.....

if someone can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the .java file and the xml file (aurelienribon/tweenengine.gwt.xml) in the build of aurelienribon. GWT needs source code and module definition file to compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,

it worked after i added the proper files,

MyGdxGame.gwt.xml  added all the packages from my src files from core

```
<source path="com/mygdx/game" />
<source path="com/stefanbanu.gameobjects" />
 .....
etc.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-      toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
 <module>
<source path="com/mygdx/game" />
<source path="com/stefanbanu.gameobjects" />
....
 </module>
```

Thanks